# Running a PHP code when pressing a submit button in html while including the information added

Tags: php, html, wordpress, submit

So, I have this submit button in my form that add the information needed to the array, however, when I open this page, it automaticlly add the information to my database(I'm using wordpress with plugin ACF with extension repeater).

What I must do, is, instead of running my php script when opening the page, to only run it when I press the submit button and include the numbers added in the form.

```
            $timea = date(d);
            if($timea<27)
                {   

                    ?>
                    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="number" name="cantpag" value="9">
                        <input type="number" name="cantreinv" value="9">

                        <input type="submit">
                    </form>
                    <?php

                    $arrayname = get_field('datos_especificos',$current_inv);
                    $arrayname[] = array(
                            'fecha'                         => 20140504,
                            'saldo'                         => 5,
                            'inversion_en_el_periodo'       => 5,
                            'interes_causado_en_el_periodo' => 5,
                            'cantidad_pagada'               => $_POST["cantpag"],
                            'cantidad_reinvertida'          => $_POST["cantreinv"],
                            'saldo_final'                   => 5
                        );


                    $field_key = "datos_especificos";
                    update_field($field_key, $arrayname, $current_inv);

                    ?>

                    <?php   

            }else{
                ?> <p>Cant do any changes after the 26th</p> <?php
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for the `GET` (although I recommend using `POST`) information before you run your update database code. Make sure you add this to the page the submission (or the current code if this is the same page) goes to. For example:

```
if( isset($_GET["cantpag"] ) {
    // Run code
}
```

This makes sure that the user entered information in the form and clicked submit. You can check for all input values but often that isn't needed.

Comment: WORKS :D, I tried the same but didnt work befor cause I was using GET at method and POST after, changed both to post, thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the form has been submitted by checking for the existence of variables in $_POST that only exist after the form is sent.

For instance:

```
if (isset($_POST['cantpag'])){

     $field_key = "datos_especificos";
     update_field($field_key, $arrayname, $current_inv);
}
```

That way the field will only be updated after the form is posted.